# Match exact string and print the line

Tags: python

I want to check if a string is matching a substring in a line after 3rd occurrence of `delimiter`

`mapping_name` = `reversed`

`delimiter` = `#`

Contents of `test_file.txt`

```
1#ABC#test#reversed_once#gm#999
2#WBC#test_1#reversed_first#gm#9998
3#TBC#tested#reversed_last#gm#9998
4#CBC#test#reversed_reversed#gm#999
5#ZBC#test#reversed#gm#9990
```

I have done like below

```
wf_string = []
batch_file = open("/home/tester/test_file.txt", 'r')

for lines in batch_file:
    if mapping_name in lines:
        print(lines)
        wf_string.append(lines)
```

But it is printing lines `4 and 5`. Ideally it should print only the `5th` line

Comment: `"search_string" in line.split('#', 3)[-1]` ?

Comment: why would you expect it to not include lines 4 and 5? they both contain the delimiter, why is 5 the selected line

Comment: Your first line has more than 3 `#` characters, so why are not expecting the first line to get printed? Also, your code never actually **uses** `delimiter`, let alone counts the occurrences of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the below (**Note** that the code assume that you want to natch against fourth field only)

```
match = 'reversed'
with open('in.txt') as f:
  for idx,line in enumerate(f,1):
    if match == line.split('#')[3]:
      print(f'match in line {idx}')
```

output

```
match in line 5
```